# how to reference data of query in a specific cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

This is what I am using, and it works fine, but whenever I add a sheet, I add it to the formula below as well.

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A:C;Sheet2!A:C;Sheet3!A:C},"select Col1,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null",0)`

I would like to have this `{Sheet1!A:C;Sheet2!A:C;Sheet3!A:C}` in a Cell, let's say `D1`
then my formula goes like this
`=QUERY(D1,"select Col1,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null",0)`.

This is just to demonstrate, and I know it will consider `D1` as the data itself

so I tried:

`indirect("D1")`

`t(D1)`

`text()`

`textjoin()`

`join()`

it always treats `D1` as the data and ignores the text in it.

Comment: This is not possible. [indirect()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) returns the cell reference provided in the string (it will give only give you the value of the cell being referenced). [query()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) expects a range of cell to query on for its 1st parameter

Comment: In addition, I don't see any benefits in moving the range to D1. When you add another sheet, you still need to modify D1. You might want to consider using [onChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#application_triggers) trigger in apps script to update your formula whenever you insert a new sheet (assuming the range is fix in `A:C` for each sheet). Just let me know if you need further support (provide a sample sheet)

Comment: the reason why I want to move the range to D1 is that I have a custom function `sheetnames()` that lists all sheets in an array then I join them in D1 like this `{sheet1A:C;sheet2A:C;....}`
everytime i add a sheet it directly updates in D1 thus the query range
thank you. @Ron M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrays of ranges are not supported under `INDIRECT` but you can generate your formula with another formula (and then just copy-paste it or use script to auto-update a given cell with the generated formula):

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA("=QUERY({"&JOIN("; ", 
 IF(B4, "IFERROR(", )&B1&SEQUENCE(B3)&"!"&B2&
 IF(B4, ", {"&JOIN(",", REGEXREPLACE(""&SEQUENCE(
 MATCH(REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "\:(.)"), CHAR(ROW(64:94)), )-(
 MATCH(REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "(^.)"),  CHAR(ROW(64:98)), )-1)), 
 "\d+", """"""))&"})", ))&
 "}, ""select Col1,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null"", 0)")}
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16jwxrdPDsaXpPTS5_1RCw51f51bhBNAo4jt25r0GguE/copy)

Comment: generating a formula by using arrayformula is a genius method, almost close to my concept ( i edited names of sheets and i use `sheenames()` to generate the list of these sheets, 
but i see A8 is not performing the function, its more likely a text , so i reference it in an other cell to perform the given function ?

Comment: @K.Robert can you share a copy of your sheet?